# Different sorting order of INNER JOIN in SQL / C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This SQL query, performed in SQL Server Management Studio displays the correct order (sorted by date).

```
SELECT Datum, Taskname, ID 
FROM ICU.dbo.TasksDatum 
ORDER BY Datum
```

`ICU.dbo.TasksDatum` is a view:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.Tasknamen.Taskname, dbo.Tasks.Datum, dbo.Tasks.ID 
FROM 
    dbo.Tasks 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Tasknamen ON dbo.Tasks.Task_ID = dbo.Tasknamen.Task_ID
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Tasks.Datum
```

In C# the sorting is different (2014, 2012, 2014, 2013 ...)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Datum, Taskname, ID FROM ICU.dbo.TasksDatum ORDER BY Datum", con);
lstTasksBenutzer.Items.Clear();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lstTasksBenutzer.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Substring(0, 10) + ": " + reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
    }
}
```

Shouldn't an `INNER JOIN` always result in random output? Why does `ORDER BY` work in Microsoft SQL Management Studio and not in C#? Is there an easy way to sort the entries by date?

Comment: Is there a chance that `lstTasksBenutzer` (whatever it is) shows items in its own order? (I'd be very surprised if `while (reader.Read())` returns items in order different from SQL one)

Comment: lstTasksBenutzer is a listbox; i dont think there is an own order.

Instead of "ORDER BY Datum" i tryed: ORDER BY ... Tasks.Datum; dbo.Tasks.Datum, ICU.dbo.Tasks.Datum.

Comment: You can easily verify whether it's the control reordering your data by sending it to Console in the loop and inspecting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember back to my GUI days, the list box has a sorted property.  If this is on, it might re-sort it regardless of the order you add data to the box.

```
listBox1.Sorted = true;
```

works, but only after using the exact same Query "ORDER BY Datum" in the VIEW and the C# Code (not ICU.dbo....).

Here is a link to C#, list box, sorted property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx